# Assigning colors to multiple datasets in a ListPlot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics, color, random

I have to generate 10-50 random real numbers:

`List[ RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {RandomInteger [{10, 10}]}]]`

This I've done, but I also have to make a ListPlot in which numbers from `1` to `10` will be `Blue`, from `0.99` to `-0.99` will be `Red` and from `-1` to `10` will be `Green`.

I tried to separate the list into `3` sublists. I also tried to use conditions but I can't make it work. Could someone help?

Comment: Have you seen `Select[]`?

Comment: There should be a solution that uses `ColorFunction` but I see nothing in the *Help*. Anyone?

Comment: @A.G. - For `ListPlot`, "`ColorFunction` requires at least one dataset to be `Joined`", i.e., it will vary the color of a line not points.

Answer (score 2):

```
rand = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, RandomInteger[{10, 50}]];
bluelist = redlist = greenlist = {};
Which[1 <= # <= 10, AppendTo[bluelist, #],
     -1 <  # <   1, AppendTo[redlist, #],
    -10 <= # <= -1, AppendTo[greenlist, #]] & /@ rand;
ListPlot[#1, PlotStyle -> #2] & @@
 Transpose[DeleteCases[
   {{bluelist, Blue}, {redlist, Red}, {greenlist, Green}}, {{}, _}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Generate `50` random pairs of data

```
SeedRandom[10];
data = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {50, 2}];
```

[`SortBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SortBy.html) the `Last` element of each pair and then split into the three groups using [`SplitBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SplitBy.html) the `Last` element

```
data3 = SplitBy[SortBy[data, Last], Abs[Last@#] > 1 &];
```

[`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html) the three groups of data

```
ListPlot[data3, PlotStyle -> {Green, Red, Blue}]
```

[image]

Comment: This breaks with `SeedRandom[778]`.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen - For `RandomSeed[778]` there is no data in the range `-1 < y < 1` so there is no split thereby resulting in a single color.

Comment: Exactly. Everything from -10 to +10 is coloured green, whereas the positive data points should be blue.

Answer (score 2):

```
CF = Which[1 <= #2 <= 10, Blue, -1 < #2 < 1, Red, -10 <= #2 <= -1, Green] &;


SeedRandom[10];
data = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {50, 2}];

options = {Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
   GridLines -> {None, {-10, -1, 1, 10}}, PlotRange -> {-11, 11}, 
   ImageSize -> Large};
```

**1.** Use `CF` as the color function setting in `ListLinePlot` with the options `Mesh -> All` (to make the points visible) and `PlotStyle -> LineOpacity -> 0` (to make lines invisible) and `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`:

```
ListLinePlot[data, Mesh -> All, PlotStyle -> LineOpacity -> 0,   
 ColorFunction -> CF, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, options]
```

[image]

**2.** Post-process `ListPlot` output to recolor points using `CF`:

```
postProcess = ReplaceAll[Point[x_] :> Point[x, VertexColors -> (CF @@@ x)]];

postProcess @ ListPlot[data, options]
```

[image]

**3.** Make each point a seperate dataset and use `CF` to style each dataset:

```
ListPlot[List /@ data, PlotStyle -> CF @@@ data, options]
```

[image]

**4.** Wrap each point with `Style` using `CF` for styling:

```
ListPlot[MapThread[Style] @ {data, CF @@@ data},  options]
```

> same picture

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?:

```
SeedRandom[10, Method -> "MKL"];
data = Transpose[{RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 50],RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, 50]}]; 
colors = Piecewise[{{RGBColor[1, 0, 0], 1 <= #[[1]] <= 10}, 
{RGBColor[0, 1, 0], -0.99 <= #[[1]] <= 0.99},
{RGBColor[0, 0, 1], -10 <= #[[1]] <= -1}}] & /@ data; 
Graphics[{PointSize[0.02], Point[data, VertexColors -> colors]}, 
AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
SeedRandom[10];
data = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {50, 2}];
d1 = Select[data, Last@# < -1 &];
d2 = Select[data, -1 <= Last@# <= 1 &];
d3 = Select[data, Last@# > 1 &];

p1 = ListPlot[{d1, d2, d3}
   , PlotStyle -> {Darker@Green, Red, Blue}
   ];
p2 = Plot[{1, -1}, {x, -10, 10}
   , PlotStyle -> {None, None}
   , PlotRange -> {-12, 12}
   , Filling -> {
     1 -> {Top, LightBlue}
     , 2 -> {Bottom, LightGreen}
     , 1 -> {{2}, Nest[Lighter, Red, 6]}
     }
   ];

Show[p2, p1]
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**
Using a `ColorFunction` is possible for a  `ListLinePlot` as @BobHanlon mentioned in the comments. Assuming that the `data2` is a list of `50` random numbers between `{-10,10}`, here are a few variations:

```
SeedRandom[10];
data2 = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 50];
If[# < -1, Style[#, Darker@Green], 
    If[# > 1, Style[#, Blue], Style[#, Red]]] & /@ data2 // Sort
```

[image]

```
GraphicsRow[ListLinePlot[#
    , ColorFunction -> 
     Function[{x, y}, If[y < -1, Darker@Green, If[y > 1, Blue, Red]]]
    , ColorFunctionScaling -> False
    , PlotRange -> {-10, 10}
    ] & /@ {data2, data2 // Sort}
 ]
```

[image]